# I want to make the bot send a message on Discord but it gives me Error in Java JDA

Tags: java, api, discord-jda

I wrote the code and it works at first, but when I type the command mentioned to the bot which is "$info" it shows me the error mentioned below. Please I need help

**testbot class**
**This is the class of the token and this code that works normally and makes the bot online without any problems, but the problem is in the second class**

```
package testbot1;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class Testbot1 {

    public static JDA jda;
    public static String prefix = "$";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {

        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("The Token Here").build();
        
        jda.addEventListener(new commands());

    }
    
}
```

**commands classThis is the class for the message that is supposed to appear when I type in discord $info, but it gives me the following problem and also tells me that the problem is from this line**

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(info.build()).queue();
```

```
package testbot1;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Testbot1.prefix + "info")) {
            EmbedBuilder info = new EmbedBuilder();
            info.setTitle("ElhadedyBot");
            info.setDescription("Currently, this bot is for testing only");
            info.setColor(0xf45642);
            info.setFooter("Created by Youssefeka116", event.getMember().getUser().getAvatarUrl());
            
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(info.build()).queue();
            info.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the error that appears when I type in Discord this command "$info"**

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.InsufficientPermissionException: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: MESSAGE_EMBED_LINKS
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.AbstractChannelImpl.checkPermission(AbstractChannelImpl.java:329)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.AbstractChannelImpl.checkPermission(AbstractChannelImpl.java:320)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.TextChannelImpl.sendMessage(TextChannelImpl.java:358)
    at testbot1.commands.onGuildMessageReceived(commands.java:19)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:445)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:151)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:952)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:839)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:817)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Answer (score 2):

> net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.InsufficientPermissionException: Cannot perform action due to a lack of Permission. Missing permission: MESSAGE_EMBED_LINKS

This tells you everything.

You try to send an embed message with

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage(info.build()).queue();
```

However, bots need the permission `MESSAGE_EMBED_LINKS` to send embed messages.

Give the bot the permission in the channel or the guild.

Note that channel permissions overwrite guild permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has already been resolved. I didn't give it permission in Discord

Comment: It does work if the bot has the permission an doesn't work if the bot doesn't have the permission.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has already been resolved. I didn't give it permission in Discord

Comment: This is literally what I wrote.